# Upgrading to new release when previous release reaches end of life

Tags: upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Since Ubuntu 12.10 has reached "end of life" I am unable to download and install softwares which I require.
when I type the following command in terminal I get the following message.

```
$ do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Err Upgrade tool signature                                                                                                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]                                                                                                                
Err Upgrade tool                                                                                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]                                                                                                                
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                             
WARNING:root:file 'raring.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

The command "Ubuntu-support-status" gives the following...

```
ashish@Ashish:~$ ubuntu-support-status
Support status summary of 'Ashish':


You have 1987 packages (100.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 0 packages (0.0%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
```

Can you  tell how to upgrade  Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or any other version...

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: try to run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 12.10 does not make much sense, because two further releases(13.04 and 13.10) are already EOL.

Therefore it's impossible<sup>#</sup> to upgrade from 12.10 to anything.

The best solution for you would be to install Ubuntu 14.04 freshly. As a plus point, you would also be able to setup things like new disk formatting(ext4 maybe), LUKS enkryption, RAID, LVM etc which can be done only at installation.

<sub># you may try to find a server which still makes it possible to upgrade from 12.10, though such a server probably doesn't exist.</sub>

Comment: At Ubuntu archives you can find old updates!All you need to do is editing repositories.